# SVN get error when revert a bad merge

Tags: svn, merge

Something wrong after I commit my **merge from a branch to trunk**. Now the version number is **689** and the previous is **687** in the **trunk tree**.

I followed the online suggestions did the following from my trunk working copy directory:

```
svn up
svn merge -r 689:687 .
```

and

```
svn up
svn merge -c -687 .
```

both above give me an error result:

> svn: E155035: Can't merge into conflicted node
>   '/locationToAFile/fileName.java'

Searched online but cannot find direct answer for this. Can you tell me how to resolve above error and let me continue the revert?

Comment: It seems like you have a merge conflict in one of your files. You need to resolve this first before you can continue to merge. Have you tried to do the reverse merge on a clean working copy? Alternatively, can you post the output of `svn st`?